# Android XML - Unable to Prevent ImageView Overlap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm attempting to prevent two images from overlapping - and I though I'd be able to do so using two RelativeLayouts inside a LinearLayout - both set to wrap_content - however the two imageViews ( `@+id/imageView1` - the boxart and `@+id/background` - the background) however they still seem to overlap.

Can someone spot what I may have done wrong in this implementation?

### XML Source:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/download"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/boxart"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="65dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/background_faded"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingBottom="65dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/downloadbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:paddingLeft="500dp"
            android:src="@drawable/button_download" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="585dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="440dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar2" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/timeline_bottom_android"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backbtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_back_arrow" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/backButtonTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/saveButton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Movies"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/downloadbtn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/downloadbtn"
            android:layout_marginRight="207dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: i think you need to read this to learn the basics of layouts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Relative layout use a Linear layout with orientation horizontal and then use two Linear layouts with layout_weight=1 for each ImageView. It will divide your screen into two equal parts horizontally.

For example :-

```
  <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"                               
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As per your given layout update your layout as follows:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/download"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/black"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/boxart"
            android:paddingBottom="65dp" />
    </LinearLayout >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background_faded"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="65dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/downloadbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:paddingLeft="500dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button_download" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="585dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="440dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/timeline_bottom_android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_back_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/backButtonTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/saveButton"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Movies"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/downloadbtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/downloadbtn"
        android:layout_marginRight="207dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think there might be a mistake or two in your answer - the beginning and ending tags do not match and I'm getting an error stating: Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at least one has layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: @NoobDev910 I have edited my answer and fixed the orientation issue,Please check the edited one, as I don't image resources like you have in your layout that is why I wasn't have clear output picture in my preview. May be you still have to make few changes with closing tags but it's not a big deal you will adjust  it easily.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but everything except the background image disappeared... 

http://imgur.com/PlfMWT6

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also - I do not wish the layout to be split in two equal parts - I want the boxart image (imageView1) to retain it's dimensions and fill - and the background to fill the remaining space - how might this be accomplished?

Comment: @NoobDev910 Let me make it give me some time.

Comment: @NoobDev910 Can I have your draw-able resources ?

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your particular situation, the 2 `ImageViews` causing problems are placed each in a `RelativeLayout`, which are also placed in a `RelativeLayout`. Views placed in a relative layout can overlap each other. So when you added the 2 children `RelativeLayouts` in the parent one, exactly this happened. To make one follow the other, you can add `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/id_of_the_layout_you_want_on_the_left_of_this_one"` to the second child.

Also, if you are willing to change your layout a bit, you could achieve this through weight and `LinearLayout` (note however that this will work only if the desired combined width of the 2 children is less than what the parent is willing to offer):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ... />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ... />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```